# Yii framework -> My before insert DB isn't triggering on save()

Tags: php, database, yii, triggers, save

I am new to the Yii framework and I can't seem to understand why this code would not function correctly. When I call the save() function, should the database insert trigger be triggered so the ID is auto generated with a UUID? if yes, it's not working since it stays NULL. Any advice?

```
$passwordRequest = new PasswordResetRequest;
$passwordRequest->userId = 2162;
$passwordRequest->save();

echo $passwordRequest->id;
echo "test";
```

Log:

```
-- Full Trigger DDL Statements
-- Note: Only CREATE TRIGGER statements are allowed
DELIMITER $$

USE `derp_app`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`%`
TRIGGER `derp_app`.`tbl_passwordReset_BINS`
BEFORE INSERT ON `derp_app`.`tbl_passwordReset`
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.id = uuid();
-- Edit trigger body code below this line. Do not edit lines above this one$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `tbl_passwordReset_BINS`;
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER `tbl_passwordReset_BINS`
BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_passwordReset` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.id = uuid();
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

This should work. Log into mysql console with your dbuser(really avoid to use root), use your database, insert trigger. 
Check it after in schema

```
SHOW TRIGGERS;
```

Must work.
May i wonder what for you use 128bit id? You imagine how large will be index on this field with even 1m records?

Comment: if I try to echo out the ID which is generated UUID. it displays nothing which means the trigger isn't happening. Is there something special about the yii framework SAVE() that I am missing on?